# Linux-wget command

Tags: linux, shell, wget

I need a quick help on customizing my [wget](/questions/tagged/wget) command in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) script:

The `wget` command looks something like this:

```
wget http://infamvn:8081/nexus/content/groups/LDM_REPO_LIN64/com/infa/com.infa. products.ldm.ingestion.server.scala/10.0.0.135.527-SNAPSHOT/com.infa.products.ldm.ingestion.server.scala-10.0.0.135.527-20150622.210643-1-sources.jar
```

Here I'd like to add the `10.0.0.135.527` in a variable, so I created a script something like this:

```
n = 10.0.0.135.527
wget http://infamvn:8081/nexus/content/groups/LDM_REPO_LIN64/com/infa/com.infa.products.ldm.ingestion.server.scala/"$n"-SNAPSHOT/com.infa.products.ldm.ingestion.server.scala-"$n"-20150622.210643-1-sources.jar
```

but this is not working, any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to create a string variable `n`, with no leading whitespace (thanks @011c):

```
n="10.0.0.135.527"
wget http://infamvn:8081/nexus/content/groups/LDM_REPO_LIN64/com/infa/com.infa.products.ldm.ingestion.server.scala/"$n"-SNAPSHOT/com.infa.products.ldm.ingestion.server.scala-"$n"-20150622.210643-1-sources.jar
```

Comment: Thanks. In the same question, can you help me on how to pass a regular expression for "20150622.210643" in my command ??

Comment: How should i give a regular expression for 20150622.210643 in wget command ? 20150622.210643 - this is basically a time stamp, so i want to handle this date-time in wget command

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: 20150622.210643 - this is basically a timestamp. I am trying to handle this timestamp through a regular expression. So instead of "20150622.210643", i will replace it with a regular expression in my wget command and if "20150622.210643" this matches my expression then the wget command is executed.

Comment: Are you trying to predict a url using a regular expresssion? Regular expressions can not do that. You have to know the url beforehand.

Comment: Not the entire URL, just the timestamp "20150622.210643". This value should be in a particular format, as it is now. I want to write a regular expression for only timestamp as shown in wget.

Comment: What would that regular expression do? Regular expressions do not generate strings, they match against them.

Comment: true, i want a regular exprssion to match the string.

Comment: the timestamp is randomly generated, i dont know the time stamp but i know the format for the timestamp. So, i want to write a regex for that timestamp ? isn't this possible ? I am too trying this for the first time

Comment: It's not possible. It's like having a device that knows how to recognize a cat, and asking it to predict what cat it's going to see next.

Comment: This answer is very misleading: OP's problem was the spaces, not the lack of quotes.